# Updating table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a 2d array, `cells` that I am using to store some `cellData` values. I have a `displayTable` function in JavaScript that I call to display this array as a table. The problem I am running into is that, after I click on a cell it's `cellType` should change to `"start"` and then, when the table is immediately redrawn, its color should change to the color specified in its style, which isn't happening. The cell's color stays the same.

```
function CellData(cellType) {
this.cellType = cellType;
this.crowFlyDistance = Number.Infinity;
this.backtrack = null;
}

function displayTable() {
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
        for(var row = 0; row < rowAndColumnSize; row++) {
        var rowToAppend = document.createElement('tr');
        for(var column = 0; column < rowAndColumnSize; column++) {
          var cellToAppend = document.createElement('td');
          cellToAppend.className = "baseCell";
          cellToAppend.className += " " + cells[row][column].cellType;
          cellToAppend.addEventListener("click", clicked);
          rowToAppend.appendChild(cellToAppend);
        }
      tableBody.appendChild(rowToAppend);
    }
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    document.getElementById("space").appendChild(table);
    }
```

I have the clicked function assigned to `selectStart` when the page first loads.  After the user selects a start location on the table the clicked function should clear the table with the `clearTable` function then make a call to `displayTable` to update the table's values.

```
function selectStart() {
    var row = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var column = this.cellIndex;
    if(cells[row][column].cellType == "empty") {
      cells[row][column].cellType = "start";
      clearTable();
      displayTable();
      clicked = selectEnd();
      alert("Select an end location.");
    }
    else alert("Select a cell that is empty.");
  }

function clearTable() {
    var tableDiv = document.getElementById("space");
    while(div.firstChild){
      div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
    }
  }
```

I have different styles defined for each cell's class, so the cell that is clicked on should change color after it is clicked. The problem is that the color of the cell stays the same, and if I set the text for each cell to contain the `cellType` for that cell it stays as empty. But if I click on the same cell twice in a row, the alert to "Select an empty cell." pops up, meaning that the `cells.cellType` value for that cell was updated. Am I doing something wrong with the way I update my table?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r4zxb11o/

Comment: create a fiddle. it would be easier to answer your question then.

Comment: In your fiddle, in the clearTable method your code says  document.getElementById("spaceTable").deleteRow(i);  
But there is no element with spaceTable id. I assume thats a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSFiddle you posted has bugs, every time the method `clearTable` was called it crashed. To remove all the elements inside `space` you can use `space.innerHTML = ''`

```
function clearTable() {
    space.innerHTML = '';
}
```

Comment: Awesome, it seems like it works perfectly now. I thought I read that using .innerHTML = ''; wasn't considered safe?

Comment: @ThomYorkkke I checked the official documentation and there aren't any notes about safety issues. http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html